# fast fonts web font not working in chrome or ie

Tags: css, webfonts

I'm trying to use a font hosted on fast.fonts.com. I am using the following code to load the font:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/3566c147-3f45-41ed-941c-cfe1528c243e.css"/>
```

In Firefox the font loads correctly, but it is not working in IE or Chrome. Do these browsers require something extra to be set up in order to work?

It's being used on this site:

http://d258eeb2b8434d14a1135347db13e724.cloudapp.net/Home.aspx

Comment: can you provide a link to website, where you use it?

Comment: The server where the fonts are hosted returns a 403 (Forbidden) response. Probably you'll have to dive into the fonts.com configuration?

Comment: i dont have access to the font.com config but the permissions have been set so that the site should have access. also if it's permissions then why does it work in firefox?

Answer (score 5):

From the fonts.com FAQ - http://www.fonts.com/support/faq/web-fonts-work-only-in-firefox

Why Are My Web Fonts Only Displaying in Firefox?

If the fonts are only working in Firefox, this may indicate that the domain listed in your Web font project are not permitted to receive the Web fonts. Review your project's domain list to ensure each domain has been specified properly. Also make sure that you've published your project since making any changes.

Answer (score 4):

Try to embed the font from fastfonts before your .css file declaration. I had the same problem with google fonts.

Comment: can you explain what you mean please?

Comment: put the `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/3566c147-3f45-41ed-941c-cfe1528c243e.css"/>` line right after `<head>` opening tag

Comment: @Barry, if you have problems with using a font service, check out the help files and FAQs, and then if needed contact the service provider. They are apparently doing something wrong, like directing your requests to addresses that return 403 Forbidden and look suspiciously like requests for TTF fonts (which don’t work on IE).

Comment: thanks for the advice jukka. what makes you think the requests are for ttf fonts?

Comment: it's not only ttf. when you take a look in `http://fast.fonts.com/cssapi/3566c147-3f45-41ed-941c-cfe1528c243e.css` you can also see fonts files requested other than ttf that works on IE (.eot and .svg)

Answer (score 3):

Chrome by default blocks http request if you are on an https site. If you remove the "http:" from your href, now the style sheet will be loaded on either http or https matching the current protocol.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//fast.fonts.com/cssapi/3566c147-3f45-41ed-941c-cfe1528c243e.css"/>
```